# how to load a few images on page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, export

I've got a trouble with display images on react page. I have directory with 30 images and I would like to display them on page (.jsx file). I know that I can export every single image, but I'm looking for much faster way to do this. Have you any ideas how to help me?:

```
dir structure:
_|app
_|src
___|images(there are images)
___|components
______|gallery.jsx
_|App.js
_|index.js
```

I tried to use `insertAdjacentHTML` function like in plain html/js page but I don't have idea how to convert that code to react where I need get div ID to insert that with loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Create React App, there is an option for public folder.

> you put a file into the public folder, it will not be processed by
> webpack. Instead it will be copied into the build folder untouched. To
> reference assets in the public folder, you need to use an environment
> variable called PUBLIC_URL.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder